# Geopy - geocoders: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Yahoo'

Tags: geopy

Team Geopy users,
I am in need of help with the above-mentioned issue. I wrote the following piece of example in preparation of a much bigger assignment:

```
## example 2:
geopy.geocoders.MapQuest = None
geocode(['13850'])
```

However, I keep getting the above-stated error which I cannot seem to find solutions for. I shall be glad for any pointers to help me fix the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to read the [geopy docs](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? Your code example makes no sense to me, unfortunately.

Comment: KostyaEsmukov, I am using 'geopandas' syntax and not that of 'geopy'; I just realized that. I tried the latter one and it's working well, but that of geopandas is the one I am having the issue with. Thanks for pointing it out to me.